# How to prevent Google ads refresh triggering window.resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-ads-api, adsense

I am working in a game project where I have placed Google Ads just before my game so that can have more impression.

The issue is that on window.resize, I am resting my game (canvas) and redraw it again to adjust in view port area.

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
    console.log("resize trigger")
    endGame();
    strikes = 0;
    $("#txtStrikes").html("<span></span>");
    score = 0;
    $("#txtScore").html("<span></span>");
    level = 0;
    drawLevelCanvas(0);
    //fitRulerToScreen();
    drawRuler();
});
```

Now issue occurs when Google Ads refresh ads and size of ads changes. It's triggering window.resize event and because of that my complete game reset in middle.

[image]

[image]

**Now I can use min-height as one alternative, but is there any way I can either stop triggering window.resize on ads refresh or distinguish between code resize and user resize ?**